# monkey patching for duck typing

Tags: python, isinstance

```
# python3.7
Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 15 2019, 16:54:46) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from collections.abc import *
>>> from _collections_abc import _check_methods
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> isinstance(a, Iterable)
False
>>> A.__iter__ = 100
>>> isinstance(a, Iterable)             # why this not working?
False
>>> _check_methods(A, "__iter__")
True
>>> class B:
...     def __iter__(self):
...             pass
... 
>>> isinstance(B(), Iterable)
True
```

I patched `A` with `__iter__`, so `isinstance(a, Iterable)` should returns `True`, since it hehaves like an iterable now for having `__iter__` defined. From the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_collections_abc.py), `Iterable` determines only based on whether the class has `__iter__` implemented.

So why does this monkey patch not working as I expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamically implementing (or un-implementing) abstract methods isn't supported. The `abc` machinery does a lot of caching to speed up `isinstance` and `issubclass` checks, and there's no option to manually reset the cache. The fact that `A` isn't a subclass of `Iterable` is cached after the first `isinstance` call, causing a `False` result for the second call.

The closest the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) come to describing the caching behavior is the following line:

> Dynamically adding abstract methods to a class, or attempting to modify the abstraction status of a method or class once it is created, are not supported.

Comment: thanks, I just realize the instance check got returned in `__instancecheck__` because of the caching in `cls._abc_negative_cache`before jumping into `__subclasscheck__`.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>you add variable `__iter__` to `a`. you must add it as a method like this</strike>:

```
 class A:
     pass

 def foo(self):
     pass

 A.__iter__ = foo
 a = A()
 isinstance(a, Iterable)
 # True
```

**UPDATE**: this answer is accidentally returns True. this just returns True because I set **iter** and then call isinstance. If I first call isinstance and then set **iter** it always returns False because of python caching system (read the answer of user2357112)

Comment: While `__iter__` does need to be a method, making it a method doesn't actually change the `isinstance` behavior. You're seeing a `True` result for other reasons - you removed the first `isinstance` check.